# Why don't use var at the beginning?

Tags: ios, swift

I learn to use the UIPageViewController in swift from this [tutorial](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/)
In the main View Controller:

```
// MARK: - Variables
private var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

// MARK: - View Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControl()
}

private func createPageViewController() {

        let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self

        if contentImages.count > 0 {
            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
            let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
            pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as! [PageItemController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        pageViewController = pageController
        addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
        pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
```

Can anyone explain for me, why we don't assign the pageViewController at the beginning like:

```
pageViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as! UIPageViewController
```

Why do we need to assign the value to the "let" variable and then assign the "let" variable to the "var" variable?

Why do we make the thing complicated? :)

Comment: `self.storyboard` is probably not immediately available (before viewDidLoad).

Comment: Maybe for scopping reasons. If it was declared inside the function, it wouldn't be available outside.

Comment: Have you tried this your approach? Does it makes any difference?

Comment: With my approach, I got this warning: " Treating a forced downcast to 'UIPageViewController' as optional will never produce 'nil' "

Comment: because we don't want to overwhelmed the initializing procedure of the class; and we need to consider to being a good memory users (as that resource is very precious and limited!), and the main principal is we load a part into a memory when it becomes necessary. the init procedure should not load any extra thing which is not sure to be used in the classes lifecycle, because after initing the class can be released immediately, and it would be pointless to load a massive amount of data which will be used only after the view loads, just for releasing it in a very next iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Your way is absolutely possible. Note there is never only one correct way to code. However, you have overlooked one side effect - `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns an optional with undefined type (`AnyObject!`) so we have to cast it to a specific type `UIPageViewController`. The side effect is that the programmer has decided to also remove the optional during that cast, using `as!` (result is `UIPageViewController` not `UIPageViewController!`).

In general it's useful to remove optionals in the beginning of every function and then use non-optionals. Since the instance variable `pageViewController` is an optional, it would be harder and less readable using it because you would have to check for `nil` (or force unwrap) for every use.

Note the difference in your code:

```
pageController.setViewControllers(...
...
pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(...
```

In my opinion the code in your example is not very good because it combines both approaches freely. Using either

```
pageViewController!.setViewControllers(...
...
pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(...
```

or

```
pageController.setViewControllers(...
...
pageController.didMoveToParentViewController(...
```

would be more readable.